Could we change which question is linked to this duplicate question?
I asked this question, and it was proposed that it be closed as a duplicate of this question. I accepted the proposal because the answer to that question indicated the specific statute related to unlawful election influence, and I thought that was helpful information.
However, soon after accepting the close proposal, I regretted my decision, because I still felt like heart of my question was unanswered: I still didn't know specifically what the prosecution claimed Trump intended to do to influence the election that would be unlawful.
This answer to another question, though, answers my question exactly ("The prosecution's theory was that the unlawful means was either: (1) FECA violations; (2) violations of tax laws; or (3) other falsification of business records.").
I think the "closed as duplicate" message will be more helpful to future readers if it links to that second question, rather than the first. Is it possible to change which question my question is closed as a duplicate of?

I've added a duplicate link to the other question, too. Thanks for the suggestion.

After Jen was so helpful and added the other as an additional dupe, this should be all handled. Thank you Jen for being a good member.
Please note that with the influx of Trump-Questions we are at the moment rather trigger-happy on closing them, at times missing the best dupe for another nigh dupe, especially with many of the questions being very close to one another.
